# Properly defining a multi-line prompt in tcsh

Tags: prompt, tcsh, csh

I am trying to configure my `prompt` in `tcsh` to make it multi-line (i.e having one line provide system info, and the next line the one where I type commands).

Currently I have the following:

```
set prompt="(remote) ${green}%n ${green}@ %m ${cyan}%~ ${white} ${end}"
```

I managed to make it multi-line by adding `%{\n>%}` at the end of it and other similar variations, but this messes my `bindkeys`

```
set prompt="(conda) ${green}%n ${green}@ %m ${cyan}%~ ${white} %{\n>%} ${end}"
```

Any thoughts on how to do this properly?

For reference, in case it matters, my `bindkeys` are:

```
bindkey "^n" history-search-forward
bindkey "^p" history-search-backward
bindkey "^r" i-search-back
bindkey "^s" i-search-fwd
```

Comment: Maybe like explained [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch04_07.htm)?

Comment: Note that if you use colour codes in your prompt, it helps to end them before any \n, then restart them after the \n. Otherwise you can confuse the terminal where its cursor is.

Answer (score 3):

I think couple of things are wrong in this propmt definition:

1. When using colors the `${end}` escape sequence have to be followed by space (this is for interpreter to correctly closes escape sequence)
2. `%{\n>%}` should be changed to `\n%{>%}` or just `\n>`

So the final prompt should be looking like:

```
set prompt="(conda) ${green}%n ${green}@ %m ${cyan}%~ ${white} \n> ${end} "
```

Comment: the '\n' character works but it requires that ' ' space before it, don't know why.